# Given points in array, find the number of points that have lower x and y value than current point

Tags: c++

I am stuck.

Given points such as (1, 0), (20, 3) e.t.c, I have to find all the points that have lower or same value as the current one (both x and y).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int N, x[15005], y[15005], level[15005] = {0};

int main()
{
  cin >> N;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) cin >> x[i] >> y[i];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      if (y[i] >= y[j] && x[i] >= x[j])
        count++;

    level[count]++;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) cout << level[i] << endl;
}
```

This is my code and you are supposed to assign 'levels' to each points (the points mean the number of points that have lower/same x and y value as the current one which is `i`th element).

Currently, I am cycling through every item in `x[]` and `y[]` to find all points that has lower/same value.

Are there any ways to make this code faster?

Note: The maximum number of dots are 15000

## Changed Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int N, X, Y, level[15005] = {0};
pair<int, int> points[15005];

int main()
{
  cin >> N;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cin >> X >> Y;
    points[i] = make_pair(X, Y);
  }

  sort(points, points + N, [](const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b)
       { return a.first > b.first; });

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      if (points[i].first >= points[j].first && points[i].second >= points[j].second)
        count++;

    level[count]++;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) cout << level[i] << endl;
}
```

Changed: sorted by x but it is still slower than what the problem wants.

Comment: Use `std::vector`. And defining a `class Point` would make the code cleaner.

Comment: Sort with key function `max(x,y)` and then it is just a matter of sweeping your array and counting the number of groups with the same level.

Comment: @Botje How do you sort (2, 3) and (3, 2)? The counting only imposes a partial order so sort + sweep won't work.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If I understand the question correctly, the order of these two elements does not matter, only how many there are with "level" 3. Come to think of it.. there is no need for sorting. Just keep a frequency table?

Comment: The order of these two elements does not matter. The answer is to just find levels (how many points have below/equal to x and y value of the current one)

Comment: @Botje (1,3) is <= than (2,3) but not <= (3, 2). The "level" 3 isn't what `y[i] >= y[j] && x[i] >= x[j]` test exactly.

Comment: Then I misunderstood. Sorry!

Comment: I think you could sort by `x` and then `j` only has to go from i+1 to the end and check `y`.

Comment: It isn't clear what sorting is meant to achieve in your code. You are still traversing all the points.